# Can not access selenium gird console

Tags: selenium, kubernetes

I have a Selenium Grid on EKS to run E2E tests.

We are trying to access the console using ALB-Ingress-Controller and DNS is created normally, but we are unable to access the console.

Is there a problem with this?

```yaml
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: selenium-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn:  acm-arn
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80},{"HTTPS": 443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
spec:
  rules:
  - host: <my-domain>
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /*
          backend:
            serviceName: ssl-redirect
            servicePort: use-annotation
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: selenium-hub
            servicePort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: selenium-hub
  labels:
    app: selenium-hub
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 4444
    name: http
  selector:
    app: selenium-hub
  type: NodePort
  sessionAffinity: None
```

When you access the domain, this page will open

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `*` to the Ingress path solved the problem

```yaml
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: selenium-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn:  acm-arn
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80},{"HTTPS": 443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
spec:
  rules:
  - host: <my-domain>
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /*
          backend:
            serviceName: ssl-redirect
            servicePort: use-annotation
        - path: /*
          backend:
            serviceName: selenium-hub
            servicePort: 80
```